# Definite steps with variable range on graph axis in Stata

Tags: for-loop, graph, stata

I am producing a number of charts in a loop, using example code below

```
forvalues i = 1/11 {
    local t: label (countryID) `i'
    twoway line Var1 Var2 Var3 year if countryID == `i', ylabel(, valuelabel grid ///
          angle(horizontal)) xlabel(1999(2)2013) xtitle("") ///
          lpattern("l" "dash_dot" "longdash") legend(size(small)) title("`t'")
    graph export output/PredictLaw`t'.png, replace
}
```

The values of each variable are labeled, but only at integer level. The variable itself can take any value between two integers, though. Consequently, I would like to ensure somehow that the yaxis uses only integers as distance, e.g. always in steps of 1.

However, since the range for each country is different, I would like Stata to determine how long the range of the y-axis has to be, as shorter ranges of course produce neater looking graphs. Hence, I would rather not use something in the form of `ylabel(1(1)21, ...`.

Is there a way to define the spacing of the y-axis, while keeping the range of the y-axis a Stata determined variable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you seek. Do you mind rephrasing? Or posting a graph(s) and describing what you want/don't want?

Comment: If you always want integer steps of 1, then the instruction necessarily will resemble `1(1)21` or `1/21`. It's hard to see that's there's any other possibility. In any case you don't say why you don't want that. You can `summarize` before each graph and make of `r(min)` and `r(max)`.

Comment: @NickCox, I was thinking about using ``r(min)`` ``r(max)`` too, but I'm not sure how to round numbers in e.g. ``r(min)`` to make sure they are integers. I will post an example graph to visualize my problem in any case, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

```
summarize whatever, meanonly 

local ymin = floor(r(min)) 
local ymax = ceil(r(max))
```

give integer results you can invoke in graph calls. The small detail here that you round down the minimum, if you do any rounding, and round up the maximum, ditto, given `floor()` and `ceil()` functions, could add a smidgen of space that suits graphical purposes.